# Display React Native Paper Snackbar at the top of the screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-paper

I'm using a [SnackBar](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/snackbar.html) from React Native Paper that is displayed at the bottom of my app:

[image]

But I want to display this snackbar at the top of the screen. I tried to do it using styled components:

```
export const ConfirmSnack = styled(Snackbar)`
  top: 0;
`;
```

But that does not do the trick, even when adding `position: absolute;` I've read the docs but can't find anything on positioning the snackbar. How can I show this snackbar at the top of the screen?

Answer (score 12):

Here's what worked for me.

```
<Snackbar wrapperStyle={{ top: 0 }} visible={true}>Casis added to basket</Snackbar>
```

**wrapperStyle**

> Style for the wrapper of the snackbar

Here's [expo link](https://snack.expo.dev/@ambatshri/snackbar-verticle-alignment) which would toggle the vertical alignment

Link to [documentation] of React Native Paper Snackbar (https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/snackbar.html#wrapperStyle)